# PowerShell Select Query With Regex Pattern as sub-expression

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to do a semi-one liner to replace the contents of a partial AD Distinguished Name column with the users actual name.

IE:

Pattern in $_.identity.DistinguishedName

```
CN=Touchdown§3939303030313134393535383932,CN=ExchangeActiveSyncDevices,CN=Guy\, Some,OU=Employees,OU=Departments and Categories,DC=something,DC=com
```

One Liner That doesn't work

```
$devices | Select @{N="Name";E={ (Get-AdUser -Identity ($_.Identity.DistinguishedName -match ".*\,CN=ExchangeActiveSyncDevices\,(.*)" | Out-Null; $Matches[1])).Name }}
```

This alone works....

```
$devices[0].Identity.DistinguishedName -match ".*\,CN=ExchangeActiveSyncDevices\,(.*)" | Out-Null; $Matches[1]
```

And Displays...

```
CN=Guy\, Some,OU=Employees,OU=Departments and Categories,DC=something,DC=com
```

This also works, which is similar to what i'm trying to achieve, but doesn't allow me to take the DistinguishedName and go lookup the actual name.

```
$devices | Select @{N="Name";E={ $_.Identity.DistinguishedName -match ".*\,CN=ExchangeActiveSyncDevices\,(.*)" | Out-Null; $Matches[1] }}
```

As soon as you try to do this it breaks down because i'm assuming your not allowed to use a ; to break to the next command when feeding that identity parameter in Get-ADUser.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity ($devices[0].Identity.DistinguishedName -match ".*\,CN=ExchangeActiveSyncDevices\,(.*)" | Out-Null; $Matches[1])
```

How would one accomplish this by using a select expression without having to populate a whole new separate variable and replace the original contents with the modified contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you're piping to Out-Null. If I understand your question, you're looking for a way to extract substrings from a regular expression? You can use Select-String; for example:

```
"Hello, world" | Select-String '^\S+, (\S+)' | ForEach-Object {
  $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
}
# outputs "world"
```

Bill

Comment: Oh, OK I think I now understand a better way to do it.  Using $_.Identity.DistinguishedName -match ".*\,CN=ExchangeActiveSyncDevices\,(.*)" returns true which is what the Out-Null was for, to cover up the true, and then I was using the matches variable to extract the actual string.  With your method we aren't returning true-false.  I was only aware of -match.  Thank You!